# Pencilblue (node.js) performance issue: constantly writing to disk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pencilblue

just got done installing my first local instance of Pencilblue. I'm running OSX 10.11 with a fresh install of node.js/mongodb/pencilblue. The very first time I ran "pencilblue start", I noticed that I could hear my HDD working feverishly. Sure enough, Activity Monitor showed "node" writing at 3MB/s!! It just kept going. I went to bed and the next morning it had written 26GB!! I ran a "killall node" and re-ran "pencilblue start", same thing, immediately started writing to disk at 3MB/s! Help!

Comment: Also, CPU usage peaked at 84%.

Comment: UPDATE: ran "node pencilblue.js" and everything is nice and quiet. Only two node processes running rather than 5, and no crazy disk writing activity. Still unsure what process is creating the disk craziness when running "pencilblue start", but my guess is that perhaps there is a bug in pencilblue.

Answer (score 1):

The only files that PB would continuously write out to would be the log files.  The log level as well as the transports can be configured.  The only time that there would be an enormous amount of log output is if your configuration has `cluster.workers = "auto"` and all of your workers (~7 on a mac book pro) were failing to make a connection to a dependent system (mongo and/or redis).

I'd be interested to see the log file to see what it was writing out.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm going to take a look this week and try to figure it out. Pencilblue's log was only 7KB at the end of it all, not sure if there are other logs elsewhere... I'm new to node.js, but understand that there are no logs out of the box, rather, instead I need to install and run node-inspector. I'll be doing that next.